# Free software to collaborate on a film/story idea

Tags: gratis, osx, collaboration

I'm looking for software that allows me and another person to privately collaborate on a film/story idea.

It should support the following content types:

- Text
- Images
- Short videos

[Groupzap](http://groupzap.com/) is an example, but it's not free and I find the skeuomorphism distracting.

Now we write everything down on paper and discuss it when we meet.
However, it's becoming harder to find common meeting times so we are trying to move our collaboration on-line. Of course real life meetings will still take place.
Also searching paper notes is becoming harder as the volume of notes increases, so a search function would help.

The purpose of this collaboration is to come up with a story which we want to convert into a short film.

**Addition:**
I see that I have not been very clear about this point: the solution should be hosted already. I don't have a webserver ready and don't plan on getting webspace for this purpose only.

Comment: What exactly does "support the following content types" mean? Should it just be possible to share/publish files of these content types, or should it be possible to edit them collaboratively?

Comment: Editing is not necessary, just sharing/publishing is fine.

Comment: Have you looked at [ownCloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ownCloud)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered a wiki?

[MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/) (which is the software that runs Wikipedia) natively supports text (with basic formatting) and images, and there are [extensions that appear useful for embedding videos](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MwEmbed). It also has pretty good full-text and page title support, and is completely free of charge.

MediaWiki can also be used for example with the [Semantic MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSemantic_MediaWiki) extension to, quoting from that web page,

> [manage] structured data in your wiki and for querying that data to create dynamic representations: tables, timelines, maps, lists, etc.

which sounds like it could be useful for a project such as what you are attempting.

You'd need a web server with PHP support and some sort of backend database to run MediaWiki, but it does not require a "server" proper (it can be run just fine on a client system). It could alternatively be hosted basically anywhere you can get web space with PHP and database (perhaps MySQL) support, with or without a login requirement to access the site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After posting my question I stumbled on this option. [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org) is an excellent comparison tool for all the different wiki options out there. The downside of a wiki is that I have to create a structure myself, it's not inherently there (as far as I know). However, if nothing else shows up I'll probably end up using a wiki (or Google Sites).